# How to select a row within APEX$ROW_SELECTOR via dynamic action

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am currently trying to select a specific row in an interactive grid via a dynamic action (as opposed to clicking on the box within the APEX$ROW_SELECTOR Column in the interactive grid).

The interactive grid is set up so that multiple rows can be selected at once and it is important that the dynamic action does not override previous row selections that were done manually.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you can use [setSelectedRecords](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.2/aexjs/interactiveGrid.html#setSelectedRecords) widget function.
As an example:

```js
// use your interactive grid region's static ID
var ig$ = apex.region("region_static_id").widget();
// use the id of the records you want to select in the array
ig$.interactiveGrid("setSelectedRecords", ["1", "2"]);
```

The ID of the records you want to be selected, can be checked by the data-id attribute of the rows in DOM structure. [image: IG data id]

Comment: Thank you for the response is there a function that returns the data-id for a row based on a column value? In addition is there a way to select every row?

Comment: apex.region("region_static_id").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").view$.grid("selectAll");
You can use selectAll method.